# How do i section a list by dividing it into more lists in python?

Tags: python, list, data-conversion

Ok so i have a list in python, for example:

```
[['02357413'], [30], ['02357413'], [22], ['02357185'], [23], ['02357185'], [24]]
```

And i want to convert it into this:

```
[['02357413', 30], ['02357413', 22], ['02357185', 23], ['02357185', 24]]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension in Python to do so as follow:

```py
>>> a = [['02357413'], [30], ['02357413'], [22], ['02357185'], [23], ['02357185'], [24]]
>>> [a[i]+a[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a)-1, 2)]
[['02357413', 30], ['02357413', 22], ['02357185', 23], ['02357185', 24]]
>>>
```